# Making a field mandatory in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a particular field (to be entered in a whole column) "Mandatory". So that if the person leaves the field empty while entering data, a dialogue box should pop up and say "This field cannot be empty" and won't let the person continue entering data any further until and unless that particular field is filled.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: This question was bumped by Community user. A common use of spreadsheets is to use them to substitute paper forms, but problems might arise when people expect to use Google Sheets to do the same as they could be done in a random system / non-disclosed system. The question doesn't include details about the dynamics of each "mandatory" "field". There are no details about the record / form structure and the steps the persons should follow.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like **Data > Data validation** cannot be used to enforce this, because validation rules apparently ignore blank cells.

Assuming the mandatory column is column `B`, try this [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers):

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetRegex = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const magicColumn = 2; // column B
  let sheet;
  if (!e
    || !e.range
    || e.range.columnStart <= magicColumn
    || !(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(sheetRegex)) {
    return;
  }
  const magicCell = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, magicColumn);
  if (!magicCell.getDisplayValue()) {
    e.source.toast(`Please enter a value in cell ${magicCell.getA1Notation()}.`);
    magicCell.activate();
  }
}
```

When a value is entered in a column `C` and up, the function will check whether column `B` is blank, and show a message if that is the case. Modify `sheetRegex` to list the sheets where you want the function to be active.

To further highlight the cell where data is missing, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule with the range `B2:B`:

```
=isblank(B2) * len(join("", C2:2))
```

Alternatively, create a [form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) for data entry, and make the field a required field.